# Summernote won't fully load

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, summernote

Hi I'm trying to use summernote but it won't fully load.
i have link all scripts and styles what it need.

```
<!-- Bootstrap3 core CSS -->
<link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- include libries(jQuery, bootstrap3, fontawesome) -->

<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src='../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<!-- include summernote css/js-->

<link href="../css/summernote.css" />
<link href="../css/summernote-bs3.css" />
<script src="../js/summernote.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/summernote.js"></script>
```

then i use JS of summernote

```
<script>
     $( document ).ready(function() {
         $('#summernote').summernote({height: 300});
     });  
</script>
```

and there is my html

```
<textarea  id="summernote" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

and after that i get this

**http://screenshot.cz/WO3ZQ/**

i have no icons here. But everything works but it looks horrible. 
I was trying to found solution and i found if I'm using bootstrap icons, i put them into  and summernote use  tag. Maybe it is the problem. I don't know.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for that, so that we can help you more, the exact problem is not identifiable by reading your question.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pW4d8/ here is jsfiddle but i can't get it work here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

updated your jsfiddle check it out now

http://jsfiddle.net/pW4d8/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#summernote').summernote({height: 300});
});
```

works just fine..

The issue was with the js resources.

edit::
this in `<head>` works fine:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/css/result-light.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://podivej.se/js/summernote.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://podivej.se/css/summernote.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://podivej.se/css/summernote-bs3.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: http://podivej.se/test.php
here is my test page on main web. I declared jquery 1.10.0 from google. Nothing change for me.

Comment: check the edit made and see if it works, because it works fine here.

Comment: change the paths of js and css acc to you.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize because I've just encountered the same problem, summernote just need to load his .js file BEFORE his own .css!

Comment: Thanks man. your solution helped me. its weird though they should stated that in their website